# Does LDF file contain Tables changes? Use of MDF in data recovery

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-recovery

Does the `.LDF` file contains table changes, added triggers and views, created stored procedures?

As I have read [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/5-basic-facts-mdf-ldf-files-sql-server/), it states that the `.LDF` file contains add and delete transactions, does that include everything that you did in the server?

I would also like to add, what is the use of the `.MDF` file?

Please do take note I have my server on Standard edition and in FULL recovery

Comment: The `.mdf` (and possibly any `.ndf`) is the actual **data file** that contains the structure and data of your database; the `.ldf` is the **transaction log file** that contains information about the transaction having been executed against your database over time

Comment: @marc_s so you mean in transaction, It also includes the table changes? added SP? sorry but I really cant understand its difference.

Comment: The `.ldf` file contains **all** transactions - and yes - adding a table, adding a stored procedure and all those DDL (Data Definition Language) operations **also** are run in the scope of a transaction. But the `.ldf` **does NOT** contain the actual table structure etc. - only the information about the transaction (did it complete successfully etc.)